# How can I fix Stripe API error: "IntegrationError: We could not retrieve data from the specified Element." in a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, stripe-payments

I'm trying to follow the new Stripe Payment Intents API [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web) to integrate a payment flow in my Vue2 project. 
Until last week, it worked smoothly. But now docs has been updated, methods I was using have been deprecated and the example in docs illustrates a different way to implements the flow.

Following the new guide, the code results:

```js
mounted: function() {
const stripe = Stripe(this.content.public_key);
const elements = stripe.elements();
const card = elements.create('card');
card.mount('#card-element');

card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

const cmp = this;
stripe.confirmCardPayment(cmp.clientSecret, {
  payment_method: {card: card}
}).then(function(result) {
  if (result.error) {
    // Show error to your customer (e.g., insufficient funds)
    console.log(result.error.message);
  } else {
    // The payment has been processed!
    if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
    }
  }
});
```

but in console appears:

```
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: We could not retrieve data from the specified Element.
          Please make sure the Element you are attempting to use is still mounted.
at new t (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:10762)
at Nr (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:44368)
at e.Mr._handleMessage (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:50022)
at e._handleMessage (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:26204)
at https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:48624
```

Do you have any suggestions to solve it?
I have already tried to use $refs to retrive card element, to use Vue NextTick, to remove async from stripe.js loading, but console throws always the same error.

Has anything to do with the vue's virtual DOM?
If I try to remove stripe.confirmCardPayment the error disappears as well as all payment confirmation flow.

Comment: Pulling my hair over this one too. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that at the time of execution of Stripe (`stripe.confirmCardPayment` in my case) the Stripe elements were removed from the DOM.

Make sure the Stripe elements are in the DOM at the time of execution. Here's an example to demonstrate what would cause this error:

```
<loader v-if="isSubmittingPayment" text="Invoking Stripe Call" />
<div v-else>
  <div id="Stripe-elements-card></div>
  <button @click="invokeStripe">Pay</button>
</div>
...
pay() {
  this.isSubmittingPayment = true // Queue offending DOM manipulation
  this.stripe.confirmCardPayment()
}
```

Comment: How do you catch error thrown by form inside confirmCardPayment?